# CS-CART Upload file after place_order

Tags: upload, hook, cs-cart

On the page checkout have tags:

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file_name"><input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" type="hidden">
```

Using hook place_order after click on confirm order button for upload file, but in function

```
fn_my_changes_place_order($order_id, $action, $order_status, $cart, $auth)
```

cant `get $_FILES data`.

Please help me! How to upload file?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, $_FILES is a super global that is for sure available on the `place_order` hook.

Comment: I need to upload a file in a hook, how can I do it? If not global variables, how do you get the file data to upload to the server?

Comment: IMO, it is better to look into controllers. Right now you are trying to change functional code and make it dependent on super globals, which is just putting a stateful requirement on a stateless function. Take a look overhere https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/core/controllers/index.html

Comment: Ideally, when placing an order, I need the user to specify the file, the file is uploaded to the server and the link to this file is added in the letter only in the email-letter to the administrator. I decided to do it using the addons and hook place_order. I initially specified the problem incorrectly